# Ansible: Jinja2 doesn't read dictionary object correctly

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

EDIT: I HAD THE WRONG FILE OPEN IN ATOM, CONTINUE TO MY ANSWER TO KNOW HOW.

I have a playbook that is supposed to spin up websites for three fictional company names, however in one of my Jinja2 templates, it doesn't find a variable that is clearly located in a dictionary. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Ansible Version:

```
ansible 2.10.13
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Jan 27 2021, 01:17:18) [GCC 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)]
```

playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: company_servers

  vars:
    company_site:
      totsuki:
        companyname: UA High School
        apache_dir: totsuki_academy
        filename: totsuki_academy
        companyid: 1
      uahs:
        companyname: UA High School
        apache_dir: ua_high_school
        filename: ua_highschool
        companyid: 2
      we:
        companyname: Wayne Enterprises
        apache_dir: wayne_enterprises
        filename: ua_highschool
        companyid: 3

  tasks:
    - name: Install Apache
      dnf:
        name: httpd
        state: latest
    - name: Create Website Folders
      file:
        path: /var/www/html/{{ item.value.apache_dir }}
        state: directory
        mode: 0775
      with_dict: "{{company_site}}"
    - name: Create HTML files
      template:
        src: htmltemplate2.html.j2
        dest: /var/www/html/{{ item.value.apache_dir }}/index.html
        owner: apache
        group: apache
        mode: 0775
      with_dict: "{{company_site}}"
    - name: Apache Preference Import
      template:
        src: httpd.conf
        dest: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
        mode: 0775
    - name: Create Configuration Folders
      file:
        path: /etc/httpd/{{ item }}
        state: directory
        mode: 0775
        loop:
          - sites-enabled
          - sites-available
    - name: Apache Preference Import
      template:
        src: httpd.conf
        dest: /etc/httpd/sites-available
        mode: 0775
    - name: Create a symbolic link
      file:
        src: /etc/httpd/sites-available
        dest: /etc/httpd/sites-enabled
        state: link
    - name: Restart Apache
      service:
        name: httpd
        state: restarted
    - name: Stop Firewall
      service:
        name: firewalld
        state: stopped
```

Infuriating Error:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 1066, in do_template
    res = j2_concat(rf)
  File "<template>", line 14, in root
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 903, in _fail_with_undefined_error
    raise self._undefined_exception(self._undefined_message)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'companyname'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/template.py", line 139, in run
    resultant = self._templar.do_template(template_data, preserve_trailing_newlines=True, escape_backslashes=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 1103, in do_template
    raise AnsibleUndefinedVariable(e)
ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'companyname'
failed: [192.168.100.6] (item={'key': 'we', 'value': {'companyname': 'Wayne Enterprises', 'apache_dir': 'wayne_enterprises', 'filename': 'ua_highschool', 'companyid': 3}}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "key": "we",
        "value": {
            "apache_dir": "wayne_enterprises",
            "companyid": 3,
            "companyname": "Wayne Enterprises",
            "filename": "ua_highschool"
        }
    },
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'companyname'"
}
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 1066, in do_template
    res = j2_concat(rf)
  File "<template>", line 14, in root
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 903, in _fail_with_undefined_error
    raise self._undefined_exception(self._undefined_message)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'companyname'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/template.py", line 139, in run
    resultant = self._templar.do_template(template_data, preserve_trailing_newlines=True, escape_backslashes=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 1103, in do_template
    raise AnsibleUndefinedVariable(e)
ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'companyname'
failed: [192.168.100.7] (item={'key': 'we', 'value': {'companyname': 'Wayne Enterprises', 'apache_dir': 'wayne_enterprises', 'filename': 'ua_highschool', 'companyid': 3}}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "key": "we",
        "value": {
            "apache_dir": "wayne_enterprises",
            "companyid": 3,
            "companyname": "Wayne Enterprises",
            "filename": "ua_highschool"
        }
    },
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'companyname'"
}
```

Also, I have noticed that Wayne enterprises 'filename' wasn't correct and I did adjust that.
It says *object has no attribute 'companyname'*

and here is my html.j2

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>{{ item.value.companyname }}</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the {{ item.value.companyname }} website</h1>
    IP Address: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your reported behavior, so I'd recommend double-checking all of your content for simple typos

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by taking a look at the path of the file I had open in Atom, and comparing it to the path of the file that Ansible was running. It's important to know, that when you're using the template module in Ansible, that files you're referencing without an exact path should be stored in ~/templates and Ansible will make that folder for you upon running a playbook with the template module.

Common sense in my mind thought it might reference the directory of the playbook, but is not how Ansible works.